# how add a new attribute in XML header tag in DOM4J

Tags: xml, dom4j

How to add a new attribute in XML header tag like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" **text1="value"**?>
```

I need to add new attribute "`text1`"

Currently it's creating in below fashion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: If you *need* to add such a thing, you're outside of the XML specification. Use another tool.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't and you are not supposed to. Or else, you are ruining the well-formedness of XML...

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the XMLWriter and override the writeDeclaration method to add  attribute.

```
@Override
protected void writeDeclaration() throws IOException {
    OutputFormat format = getOutputFormat();
    String encoding = format.getEncoding();

    // Only print of declaration is not suppressed
    if (!format.isSuppressDeclaration()) {
        // Assume 1.0 version
        if (encoding.equals("UTF8")) {
            writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"");

            if (!format.isOmitEncoding()) {
                writer.write(" encoding=\"UTF-8\"");
            }

            // TODO Add your attribute hear
            writer.write(" standalone=\"yes\"");

            writer.write("?>");
        } else {
            writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"");

            if (!format.isOmitEncoding()) {
                writer.write(" encoding=\"" + encoding + "\"");
            }

            // TODO Add your attribute hear
            writer.write(" standalone=\"yes\"");

            writer.write("?>");
        }

        if (format.isNewLineAfterDeclaration()) {
            println();
        }
    }
}
```

result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```